# Punctured torus and two circles intersecting at a point

Tags: general-topology

A torus can be represented by a square with opposite sides identified. I read somewhere that the boundary of the square with opposite sides identified is, in fact, the graph of two circles intersecting at a point. May I know why?

Comment: Think about where the boundary of the square ends up as you make the entire square into a torus.

Comment: Check the image [Torus from rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#/media/File:Torus_from_rectangle.gif) and [Torus cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#/media/File:Torus_cycles.svg) from Wikipedia.

Comment: Ah...it is the same as forming the torus. Thanks, Arthur!